# Limit of $\frac{f(1+h)-f(1-3h)}{5h}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, proof-explanation

> Assume that a function $f$ satisfies the condition $f'(1) = 2.$ Figure out the limit $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1-3h)}{5h}.$$

This seemed to be a very simple problem just dealing with the definition of a derivative, but the proposed solution was a bit confusing. It went as follows:

Adding $-f(1)$ and $f(1)$ to the numerator we get

$$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1-3h)}{5h} = \frac{f(1+h)- f(1) +f(1)-f(1-3h)}{5h}. \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This can be simplified to

$$\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{5h} + \frac{f(1)-f(1-3h)}{5h}. \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

And now from here we get

$$\frac15 \cdot \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} + \frac35 \cdot \frac{f(1)-f(1-3h)}{3h}. \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Furthermore

$$\frac15 \cdot \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} + \frac35 \cdot \frac{f(1-3h)-f(1)}{-3h}. \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Now taking the limit $h \to 0$, we have that

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac15 \cdot \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h} + \lim_{h\to0} \frac35 \cdot \frac{f(1-3h)-f(1)}{-3h} = \frac15\cdot f'(1) + \frac35\cdot f'(1) = \frac85$$

Could someone educate me on parts $(3)$ and $(4)$. Why do we chose $\frac35$ in $(3)$ instead of $\frac15$? If we would have taken out $\frac15$ the result would have been $\frac15\cdot f'(1) + \frac15\cdot f'(1) = \frac45$ right? Also what's happening on $(4)$ how do we suddenly flip the numerator?

Comment: Those numbers were chose to modify the denominators to match the step size inside of the functions. Notice that as long as the step sizes shrink at exactly the same rate, we retrieve the same familiar limit from the definition of the derivative.

Comment: A key thing to remember is that the definition of the derivative is $$\large f'(x)=\lim_{\color{blue}h\to0}\frac{f(x\color{blue}{+h})-f(x)}{\color{blue}h}.$$

Provided that $\color{blue}h$ is the same non-zero value wherever it has to appear in the definition, you can rewrite the limit as $f'(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}h=2.$$This means that, for every number $a\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$,$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(1+ah)-f(1)}{ah}=2,\tag1$$too. Those manipulations were done so that you had to deal with limits of the form $(1)$.

Comment: In $(1)$ was the $h$ at the end a typo or should we multiply the numerator by it?

Comment: It was a typo. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing $\frac{1}{5}$ instead of $\frac{3}{5}$ would not have worked because $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(1-3h) - f(1)}{-h} \neq f'(1)$$

Comment: So since we have $3h$ in the numerator we would have to have $-3h$ in the denominator as well in order it to equal $f'(1)$?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic idea. Define $a(h):=\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$. Since $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} a(h)=f'(1),$ the function $a(h)$ is continuous at $h=0$. Take any function $g(h)$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} g(h)=0$. Then
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}a(h)=\lim_{h\to 0}a(g(h))=f'(1).
$$
In both difference quotients, the idea is to come up with an appropriate $g(h)$. For the first term, it's written as 
$$
\frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{5h}.
$$
When $1/5$ gets pulled out, it becomes just the standard definition of a derivative so we leave it (i.e. $g(h)=h$)

For the second term,
$$
\frac{f(1)-f(1-3h)}{5h}=\frac{f(1-3h)-f(1)}{-5h},
$$
the most sensible substitution is to say $g(h)=-3h$ in an effort to replicate $f(1+g(h))-f(1)$, but we see that the denominator in the difference quotient is not $g(h)$. We want the denominator to be $g(h)=-3h$. Hence, pull out $1/5$ and multiply and divide by $3$. Then it becomes
$$
\frac{3}{5}\frac{f(1+g(h))-f(1)}{g(h)}.
$$
This will now evaluate to $\frac{3}{5}f'(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
since
$f(x+h)
\approx f(x)+hf'(x)+O(h^2)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{f(x+ah)-f(x+bh)}{h}
&=\dfrac{f(x)+ahf'(x)+O(h^2)-(f(x)+bhf'(x)+O(h^2))}{h}\\
&=\dfrac{(ah-bh)f'(x)+O(h^2)}{h}\\
&=(a-b)f'(x)+O(h)\\
\end{array}
$

Here
$x=1, a=1, b=-3$
so
the result is
$4f'(1)/5
=8/5
$.